# Using VBA to open & save an online dynamic-name file

Tags: vba

I keep template files on our SharePoint (.xlsx), with the active one in the main folder and all older versions moved to an Archive folder in said main folder.  I label by date (yyyymmdd) followed by "Template" for each update, e.g. 20161206 Template.

I know that I can use the Workbooks.Open("http://www.website.com/") function in VBA to open a file, but I am not sure how to open a dynamic named file from the internet.

I was thinking of something like:

```
Sub OpenFromInternet()

Dim DateChk As String
DateChk = 'Not sure

Workbooks.Open "http://www.website.com/" &DateChk& " Template.xlsx"

End Sub
```

The DateChk is where I have been getting stuck... I don't know what would even be an efficient way of going about this problem.  Considering I only keep one file in the main folder with the date in it, I tried a wildcard (asterisk) for the DateChk and it didn't work.

Any input would be appreciated in figuring out how to get that DateChk to be meaningful.

---

Edit 01:

Trying this code:

```
Sub OpenFromInternet()

Dim wbk As Workbook
    Set wbk = Workbooks("http://www.website.com/Update Log.xlsx")

Dim LR As Long
    LR = Cells(wbk.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim DateChk As String
    DateChk = Workbooks("http://www.website.com/Update Log.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & LR).Value

Workbooks.Open "http://www.website.com/" & DateChk & " Template.xlsx"

End Sub
```

The issues I'm getting are related to trying to define an online workbook (run-time error 9, subscript out of range).  I would have like to have have to have another file to update, but I guess that is easier for me to maintain than for others... just have to remember it.

Still working through this.

---

Edit 02:

I have this code which works:

```
Sub OpenFromInternet()

Workbooks.Open ("http://www.website.com/Update Log.xlsx")

    Dim LR As Long
        LR = Cells(Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim DateChk As String
    DateChk = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & LR).Value

Workbooks("Update Log.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=False

Workbooks.Open "http://www.website.com/" & DateChk & " Template.xlsx"

End Sub
```

I feel it's pretty inefficient, but solves the issue... I'd like to get away from having a second file have to be both maintained and used (open, close).

Any help to circumvent this second workbook would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Edit 02 for functioning code.

Will ask about referencing online workbooks in another question, since the question I originally asked was answered, regardless of what I thought I intended by asking as I did.